# ios - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I was using an UIViewController in Swift but I get it when I try to persist the data and trying to retrieving it to back in application.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var linefields:[UITextField]!

    func dataFilePath() -> String {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
            NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,
            NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
        let documetnDirectory = paths[0] as! NSString
        return documetnDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.plist") as String
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let filePath = self.dataFilePath()

        if (NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(filePath)){
            let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath) as! [String]
            for (var i=0;i<array.count;i++){
                linefields[i].text = array [i]
            }
        }

        let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,selector: "applicationWillResignActive:",name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification,
            object: app)

    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(notification:NSNotification){
        let filePath = self.dataFilePath()
        let array = (self.linefields as NSArray).valueForKey("text") as! NSArray
         //-----> Next line: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
        array.writeToFile(filePath, atomically:true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Does anyone know about this?

[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly the most common exception reported for Swift on Stack Overflow.  What debugging have you attempted?  Try setting an exception breakpoint to determine which line is causing the exception.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you be more specific on what line is your code returning a nil as well as what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: My guess is that `(self.linefields as NSArray).valueForKey("text")` is returning `nil`

Comment: @originaluser2 the `valueForKey` method on `NSArray` returns a new array that results from getting the value of the specified key on all objects in the array, so while I agree that this line is the probably problem, `valueForKey("text")` is valid

Comment: @Paulw11 ah ok, didn't know that! Interesting to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your connections from textFeilds (storyboard file ) to Outlets(swift file). Because missing connections would return nil.

Answer (score 0):

This is swift's error for when you tell it there will be a value in a certain variable, but there was not one. Basically, one of the variables you were reading data from had no data, because for some reason it had never been assigned data.

As commenters have recently said, it is probably this line: `(self.linefields as NSArray).valueForKey("text") as! NSArray`. My advice is to switch the `as!` to `as?` or `as`, because this won't tell swift, "there is definitely a value here." Other comments have suggested trying to substitute this potential problem line with something simpler and use the `map()` function more carefully elsewhere in your code.

Comment: switching as! to as? is not helping me.